# How to get names of Whatsapp Contact on an Android

Tags: android, contacts, whatsapp

My code is here I want to get contact name.How to get whatsapp contact name.

```
String adress = intent.getStringExtra("contact");
                String phone = adress.split("@")[0];
                String[] projection = new String[] {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NORMALIZED_NUMBER };
                ContentResolver cr=getContentResolver();
                String selection = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NORMALIZED_NUMBER + " = " + phone;
                Cursor c = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, null, null);
                int contactnameColumn=c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.RawContacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY);
                if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "name: "+ c.getString(0));
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"name:"+c.getString(0),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

Comment: Here is a sample where you get list of contacts in Android : https://github.com/Ali-Rezaei/Contacts

Comment: I can open the contact list, but I can't get the name of the person I chose.